# How to fix TypeError: transform(...) is null

Tags: dojo, dgrid

Another individual said this error is generally caused by "a widget template that is referencing a property via ${...} that doesn't actually exist in the widget."

I've researched and can't seem to find a way to resolve this error. Any advice or leads to help solve this issue? How do you FIND this bit of code to correct the issue?

Comment: Do you have a traceback that could help provide some more context to your question? Also, if the other individual said that on a mailing list or SO, can you provide links to what you have already looked at?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I was able to correct the issue... or at least that one. :) Answer and resources are posted (as well as the stack trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some assistance from SitePen.

Here's the trace Stack -

**string.substitute/<()string.js (line 147) string.substitute()string.js

> (line 141) ._updatePaginationStatus()Pagination.js (line 395) 
>   .gotoPage/
>
> return transform(value, key).toString();
>
> instrum...tion.js (line 20)**

The Pagination was failing - potentially trying to pull data before it was actually there. 
"Code is trying to do a string.substitute call, but the transformation you're trying to do isn't valid. It looks like the Pagination extension is failing on this. Given the number of steps related to Deferreds, it looks like something is trying to parse data before that data is available. For example, you have an async call, but are treating the data synchronously.

That said, when using the Pagination extension, I think you use the normal Grid rather than the OnDemandGrid."

I switched from OnDemandGrid to Grid - left pagination. Error still there. Switched back to OnDemandGrid - eliminated Pagination. Error Gone.

Also found this little note that I had overlooked in documentation: *"Note that the Pagination extension is incompatible with OnDemandGrid, since each has its own way of dealing with collection ranges. Pagination should be mixed into Grid, not OnDemandGrid."*

http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/

## thankyousitepen

Comment: you can mark your answer as answered, if it has solved the issue.